# DCEVM and Scala class reloading

Tags: java, scala, hotswap, dcevm

First of all, let me just say that searching from `DCEVM Scala` was surprisingly fruitless.

Use case: I have an SBT project which mixes Java and Scala classes. I want to perform hotswapping on it, using Hotswap Agent and DCEVM.

Problem: Java classes are reloaded, Scala classes are not.

I've created a sample SBT application to demonstrate that: https://github.com/keynmol/dcevm-scala

As I was writing this question, I tried it without DCEVM and it annoyingly worked. So the question is - how to make DCEVM work with Scala?

Comment: Hey Anton. You can try to contact with @DavidFrank from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27966375/2650174). From his question: _I use DCEVM to reload classes in my Scala application_ just ask under question who he got it done )